# width incorrect once I make image fullwidth

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a container of 3 800x200 images

normally their container width should be about ~2400. all is fine but once I add width: 100%; to the images then the container width is equal cu 100vw

I don't understand why is this happening ? Adding width: 100%; to a display block element should make no difference really.

Example:

[image: width]

the only difference between the containers is that the second has width: 100%; applied to the images

code - http://codepen.io/digitalzoomstudio/pen/eBBjNL

```
.fullwidth{
  display:block;
}
.fullwidthwithwidth100{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The containers have `white-space:nowrap` and the `.csc-item` has `display:inline`.

This means that the container when not having a specific width, will expand to contain its contents (*and since `nowrap` applies it will expand its width*).

On the case where you set a width on the container, you force it to have that width (*fixed and inherited from its own container*) and so will not expand to contain its contents. The contents will just overflow it.